# Run a powershell script if in a specific group

Tags: powershell

I have a windows 2016 server that is joined to a domain where i am going to run a script each time a user logins to the server. Is it possible to make the powershell script check if the user is in the administration group with like an if / if else? If they are in the administration group the script stop, but for everyone else it should it should continue on.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm sure you've already taken the [Tour] and you've read the help topic [Ask]. If not - please do so before proceding. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sure Is possible, please click the links provided by Olaf and we'll be glad to assist once corrections have been made.

Answer (score 0):

Would this not be better done by a GPO with scheduled tasks instead? It would simplify the script to start, and much easier to deploy to particular users/groups.